# Angular APP_INITIALIZER does not work on (Android) mobile phone

Tags: angular, initialization, loading

I would like my website to load all data (through API calls) before showing the page, as the data is needed by the components.

On the internet there is a solution with APP_INITIALIZER, which works perfectly on desktop computers, but shows a blank page on mobile (Android) phones:

https://medium.com/@mohd2sh/load-data-before-the-app-starts-in-angular-2-3b1927aa502c

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Sorry, problem solved, it needed a https connection on the phone. Sorry!!!

Comment: but how can I redirect my phone to https, so that it really shows the page?